# Split string by paragraph tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with bbcodes. I need to split string to array by [p] tag. Example of string:

```
[p][b][size=3][br][/size][/b][size=3][b]COMPANY INFORMATION[/b]
[/size][br][ul][li][size=3]PM1[/size][/li][li][size=3]Pure[/size]
[/li][li][size=3]Each of these agreements.[/size][/li][li][size=3]
[url=/4b63cf8214dbd6c3ef17128e8fb5a49101414715.jpeg]Capital 
Structure[/url][/size][/li][li][size=3]Capital[/size][/li][/ul][/p]
[p]fdgdfgdfg dfgdfkgjdf;glk 
khghjghjghjghjghjghjghjghjghjj [url=/fghfghfgh.jpg]
[size=3]Jira[/size][/url][/p][p]sgsdfsdf sdf sf sdf sdf s dfs dfs 
df ffkfkgkdkfgjdsfggggk gkgk sdfigjdsufioguds gfgigigigig ggigig ig[/p]
```

And as result, I want to have an array like this:

```
[
  0: "[b][size=3][br][/size][/b][size=3][b]COMPANY INFORMATION[/b][/size][br][ul][li][size=3]PM1[/size][/li][li][size=3]Pure[/size][/li][li][size=3]Each of these agreements.[/size][/li][li][size=3][url=/4b63cf8214dbd6c3ef17128e8fb5a49101414715.jpeg]Capital Structure[/url][/size][/li][li][size=3]Capital[/size][/li][/ul]"
  1: "fdgdfgdfg dfgdfkgjdf;glk khghjghjghjghjghjghjghjghjghjj [url=/fghfghfgh.jpg][size=3]Jira[/size][/url][/p][p]sgsdfsdf sdf sf sdf sdf s dfs dfs df ffkfkgkdkfgjdsfggggk gkgk sdfigjdsufioguds gfgigigigig ggigig ig"
  ...
]
```

Now, I can do only like this:

```
string.split(/[\[\]]/g).filter((value) => {return value !== ""}
```

It's give me all tags by separate element of result array

Comment: So, split it on `[p]`, and remove all `[/p]`

Comment: try `b = a.split("[p]").map( function(item){ return item.replace("[/p]", "" ); }); b.shift();` b is your output array

Comment: @gurvinder372 it's not help for me

Comment: It works for the sample data you have shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd solve it with a regex. I used a capture group which will return everything between `[p]` and `[/p]`.

```js
const
  inputString = '[p][b][size=3][br][/size][/b][size=3][b]COMPANY INFORMATION[/b][/size][br][ul][li][size=3]PM1[/size][/li][li][size=3]Pure[/size][/li][li][size=3]Each of these agreements.[/size][/li][li][size=3][url=/4b63cf8214dbd6c3ef17128e8fb5a49101414715.jpeg]Capital Structure[/url][/size][/li][li][size=3]Capital[/size][/li][/ul][/p][p]fdgdfgdfg dfgdfkgjdf;glk khghjghjghjghjghjghjghjghjghjj [url=/fghfghfgh.jpg][size=3]Jira[/size][/url][/p][p]sgsdfsdf sdf sf sdf sdf s dfs dfs df ffkfkgkdkfgjdsfggggk gkgk sdfigjdsufioguds gfgigigigig ggigig ig[/p]',
  paragraphRegex = /\[p\](.*?)\[\/p\]/gi,
  paragraphs = [];
  
let 
  match;
  
while ((match = paragraphRegex.exec(inputString)) !== null) {
  // The result of the capture group is at index 1 of the match.
  paragraphs.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(`Number of paragraphs found: ${paragraphs.length}`);

paragraphs.forEach((paragraph, index) => console.log(`Paragraph ${index}: "${paragraph}"`));
```